# Get only Text part from HTML

Tags: editplus

I have an HTML page opened in EditPlus.I want to remove all the HTML tags i.e. all the <> tags from it so that I am only left with the text part.What regex do I need to put to remove these.I tried <.> since . means any character but it did not work.Can anyone suggest how I can achieve this?

Answer (score 0):

You may use this regexp to find for all HTML tag

```
<([A-Z][A-Z0-9]*)\b[^>]*>(.*?)</\1>
```

and replace with `$2`